# ReactTooltip has wrong position after scrolling

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, css-position, react-tooltip

I use the ReactTooltip Component from 'react-tooltip' package. In my application, I have a scrollable modal in which the tooltips are used on some text. When I scroll in the modal, the tooltips get an offset in y direction and I dont know why. Could someone help me anchoring the tooltips so that they stick to the text they are applied on instead of moving when I scroll down?

Here is a picture of the issue:
[image]

Comment: Could you show the relevant code?

Answer (score -1):

Might be that tooltip position is wrongly calculated when scrolling inside the modal... Since in that case scrolling fires not inside the window but modal instead. You can use **overridePosition** property, calculate and overwrite y position of the tooltip.

Comment: Hi! :) could you expand a bit more your solution? I haven't been able to solve it. I executed `ReactTooltip.rebuild()` inside `overridePosition` but it did not work in all cases